# Vuetify 3 : v-menu location property not working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

i have a v-menu on toolbars right corner. The menu displays as bottom right (end) so half the card is outside the view. I want to change to bottom left (start) however i can't seem to make it work.

```
<v-menu
        location="start"
        rounded
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-btn
            icon
            v-bind="props"
          >
            <v-avatar
              color="brown"
              size="large"
            >
              <span class="white--text text-h5">{{ user.initials }}</span>
            </v-avatar>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>
            <div class="mx-auto text-center">
              <v-avatar
                color="brown"
              >
                <span class="white--text text-h5">{{ user.initials }}</span>
              </v-avatar>
              <h3>{{ user.fullName }}</h3>
              <p class="text-caption mt-1">
                {{ user.email }}
              </p>
              <v-divider class="my-3"></v-divider>
              <v-btn
                rounded
                variant="text"
                @click="() =>  goSettings() "
              >
                Settings
              </v-btn>
              <v-divider class="my-3"></v-divider>
              <v-btn
              @click="() => logOut()"

              >
                Disconnect
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-menu>
```

I'm missing somethings? im checking the example in the docs https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/

thanks

edit: added screenshots of current behaviour vs expected

[image: current behaviour]

[image: expected behaviour]

Edit 2: I tried the v-menu on a codepen and works as intended, however for some reason, it does not work inside a v-app-bar

Comment: Could you provide screenshots how does it behave and what is expected behaviour?

Comment: I just added the screenshots of current and desired behaviour :) !

Comment: Yes, I tried yourcode  in codepen as well and it seems to be working ok, make sure you use the latest version of vuetify, or create a new issue on [github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+menu)

Answer (score 0):

Try using prop "anchor" instead of "location".

```
<v-menu
    anchor="bottom end"
    rounded
  >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
      <v-btn
        icon
        v-bind="props"
      >
        <v-avatar
          color="brown"
          size="large"
        >
          <span class="white--text text-h5">{{ user.initials }}</span>
        </v-avatar>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
          <v-avatar
            color="brown"
          >
            <span class="white--text text-h5">{{ user.initials }}</span>
          </v-avatar>
          <h3>{{ user.fullName }}</h3>
          <p class="text-caption mt-1">
            {{ user.email }}
          </p>
          <v-divider class="my-3"></v-divider>
          <v-btn
            rounded
            variant="text"
            @click="() =>  goSettings() "
          >
            Settings
          </v-btn>
          <v-divider class="my-3"></v-divider>
          <v-btn
          @click="() => logOut()"

          >
            Disconnect
          </v-btn>
        </div>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-menu>
```

I can't even tell you why this could work, because I wasn't able to find it in the Docs or Files, but it is used like that in one of the templates I'm using.
However, this only works for large screens, on mobile the card will be outside the view again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution is using the activator prop or perhaps, in your case you sould use the internal-activator prop.

```
<v-menu
        location="start"
        rounded
        internal-activator
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-btn
            icon
            v-bind="props"
          >
            <v-avatar
              color="brown"
              size="large"
            >
              <span class="white--text text-h5">{{ user.initials }}</span>
            </v-avatar>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>
            <div class="mx-auto text-center">
              <v-avatar
                color="brown"
              >
                <span class="white--text text-h5">{{ user.initials }}</span>
              </v-avatar>
              <h3>{{ user.fullName }}</h3>
              <p class="text-caption mt-1">
                {{ user.email }}
              </p>
              <v-divider class="my-3"></v-divider>
              <v-btn
                rounded
                variant="text"
                @click="() =>  goSettings() "
              >
                Settings
              </v-btn>
              <v-divider class="my-3"></v-divider>
              <v-btn
              @click="() => logOut()"

              >
                Disconnect
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-menu>
```